# Using width property or style width on col tags?

Tags: html, css, col

I want to know if there's a difference between the width property and width attribute from style in order to define the size of columns from a colgroup of a table in HTML

```
<colgroup>
<col width="15" />
</colgroup>


<colgroup>
<col style="width:15px;" />
</colgroup>
```

I have to standardize many pages but I want to know if there is a specific difference between them, html support, performance or compatibility between browsers or HTML versions...etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what I saw the only difference is that in the HTML5 width attribute is no longer supported

```
The <col> width attribute is not supported in HTML5.
```

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_col_width.asp